# problem with running two threads on raspberry pi

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, video-streaming, streaming

I have a streaming program that sends frames of captured video taken by picamera from raspberry to server and another program that receive some characters from server. when I run them individually there is no problem but i want them to run them simultaneously to do some functions when for example 'a' pressed on server so i threaded them but it makes streaming so slow. Is there any solution to fix this problem?

server.py:

```
def get_input(c):
    #getting input characters from keyboard and send them to raspberry 
def get_video(c):
    #getting video frames form raspberry 

thread.start_new_thread(get_video, ("2",))
thread.start_new_thread(get_input, ("1",))

while 1:
    pass
```

raspberry.py:

```
def get_input(c):
    #getting input chars from server
def send_video(c):
    #sending video frames to server

thread.start_new_thread(send_video, ("2",))
thread.start_new_thread(get_input, ("1",))

while 1:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the problem you need first to find out what is the reason of it.

One obvious problem here is that this code:

```
while 1:
   pass
```

executes a [busy loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). So it uses CPU resources but does nothing substantial. You may replace `pass` with `sleep(0.1)` there or [wait for thread to finish](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) (this would require however to switch to [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module)

Another possible problem may be the similar issue in `get_input` (you haven't shown its source). Make sure you don't have any busy waiting there. Some small `sleep` (50-100 ms) should be enough to give time for other thread to execute and would not affect user experience much.

In general use [profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to check where you program spends time.

Comment: thanks my problem solved by changing pass to time.sleep(.05)